# Cannot deserialize value of type

Tags: java, spring-boot, websocket, jackson, sockjs

I try to create interactive apllication and working with sockets.
I send data by postman in socket, but SpringBoot cannot deserialize it. Pleasr, help)

[image]

**My dto**

```
public class Event {
    @JsonProperty("eventType")
    private String eventType;

    public Event(String eventType) {
        this.eventType = eventType;
    }

    public String getEventType() {
        return eventType;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Event{" +
                "eventType='" + eventType + '\'' +
                '}';
    }
}
```

**Controller**

```
@Controller
public class GameController {

    @MessageMapping("/emit")
    @SendTo("/topic/events")
    public Event emitEvent(Event event) {
        return event;
    }
}
```

**Error**

```
2022-02-23 16:19:41.359 ERROR 12468 --- [nio-8080-exec-6] s.w.s.s.t.s.WebSocketServerSockJsSession : Broken data received. Terminating WebSocket connection abruptly

com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.MismatchedInputException: Cannot deserialize value of type `[Ljava.lang.String;` from Object value (token `JsonToken.START_OBJECT`)
 at [Source: (String)"{
    "eventType": "TestData"
}"; line: 1, column: 1]
```

Update 1:

[image]

Comment: Also, i note, that `[Ljava.lang.String;` - is so strange, it looks like broken string (type), but i dont know, why it's here apeared...

Comment: `[Ljava.lang.String;` is `String[].class`

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that with the tool that you send the request (I suppose it is postman) you send it as raw text. So the desirializer expects it to be a simple String and so it can not convert it into a complex object.

You should have informed the controller that what it receives is a Json request, so that it can parse it with the correct `message body reader` and convert it into a `Event` object.

To do so, use the following header in your request you make

```
Content-Type: application/json
```

Also the problem here seems to be the url that you use to send the message. This url does not seem to represent the controller endpoint which should end with `emit`. I think you send the request directly to the message broker and not the controller of the application.

Comment: Thanks a lot, but it's socket requests. I was added application/json, but error remains

Comment: I cannot delete this s*it ) Postman cannot allowed it

Comment: aready, do it a lot of times

Comment: i'l tried it. Not working

Comment: @kepich check updated answer, the url that you use seems to not correspond to the controller. Probably you are making a request directly to the broker and not the application controller. Check here an example of how it can be used https://spring.io/guides/gs/messaging-stomp-websocket/